# how to install setuptools in mac

Tags: python, django, macos, installation, pip

I'm trying to install via `pip` some libraries but I'm having some problems.

When I try to install some of them I require for my project I get this message:

```
$ sudo pip install dj-database-url==0.2.0
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url==0.2.0
  Downloading dj-database-url-0.2.0.tar.gz
Cleaning up...
setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
```

It also happens when trying to install `distribute==0.6.24`

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `sudo pip install` ever - you will face problems later. Use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Download `ez_setup.py` module from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
2. Open a *Terminal*.
3. `cd` to the directory where you put the `ez_setup.py`.
4. Type `python ez_setup.py` and run it.
5. You should have it then.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was on the page at the time of this answer, but the section [Unix including Mac OS X (curl)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-including-mac-os-x-curl) provides a command `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python`, which does exactly as described in answer, just with a single action and without having to download/remove the file explicitly. AFAIK `curl` is pre-installed on every Mac OS X system.

Comment: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python` gives me error `File "<stdin>", line 1
    <html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: This method is now deprecated: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581

Answer (score 0):

After a *pip install* command I was getting the same error as you ("*setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution*"). Since I couldn't find a solution, it was a lot faster to reinstall the virtual environment where python was running from.

If you're using virtualenvwrapper this is very easy. First you remove your problematic virtual environment (let's say it is called "venv") with:

```
rmvirtualenv venv
```

Then you setup a new one with the same name:

```
mkvirtualenv venv
```

And finally you install all your packages, including the one you had problems with:

```
pip install dj-database-url
```